# Pass array between functions in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, parameters, codeigniter-3

How can I pass an array from one function to the other one, and add both arrays in Codeigniter?

**Here is my code:-**

This is the URL of form i use when submit the data.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('Welcome/payment_page');?>">


 public function payment(){
    
     $data['userid']  = $this->input->post('userid');
     $data['payment']  = $this->input->post('payment');
        if(!empty($data)){
            $this->payment_page($data); //passing data into another function
         }
         $this->load->view('frontend/include/header');
         $this->load->view('frontend/payment');
    }
    
    
    public function payment_page($data = ''){
       $data;
       
       $other_data=array(
        'cardname' => $this->input->post('cardname'),
           'cardno'=> $this->input->post('cardno'),
          'cardcvv'=> $this->input->post('cardcvv'),
        'cardmonth'=>$this->input->post('cardmonth'),
        'cardyear' =>$this->input->post('cardyear')
        );
        
        $main_data = array_merge($data, $other_data);
        
        
    }
```

**Its giving me error :-**

```
Severity: Warning

Message: array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, string given
```

Comment: Could you try to use `function payment_page($data = [])`?

Comment: @Tartarus when I initialize with empty array it gives me second array only.

Comment: I added another solution, could you try it?

Comment: is this in the same controller functions or controller + model?

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam in the same controller functions.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you set for `payment_page($data = '')` is a string, not an array. You  have to initialize it with an empty array instead of an empty string
So it has to be like

```
function payment_page($data = [])
```

Comment: when I initialize with empty array it gives me second array only.

Comment: try to make is like payment_page($data) with not initialization

Answer (score 0):

Init with an empty array

```php
public function payment_page($data = [])
```

In case the above code not working, you can try another way.

```php
public function payment_page(&$data = [])
```

Comment: when I initialize with empty array it gives me second array only.

Comment: @KUMAR maybe you should check that it goes through `function payment()` or not.

Comment: yes it goes but when after i again submit the form action goes to second function it show only second array data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to **return** the merged array. Try this:

```
public function payment(){
 $data['userid']  = $this->input->post('userid');
 $data['payment']  = $this->input->post('payment');
    if(!empty($data)){
        $this->payment_page($data); //passing data into another function
     }
     $this->load->view('frontend/include/header');
     $this->load->view('frontend/payment');
 }
 public function payment_page($data){
   $other_data=array(
    'cardname' => $this->input->post('cardname'),
       'cardno'=> $this->input->post('cardno'),
      'cardcvv'=> $this->input->post('cardcvv'),
    'cardmonth'=>$this->input->post('cardmonth'),
    'cardyear' =>$this->input->post('cardyear')
    );
   $main_data = array_merge($data, $other_data);
   return $main_data;
}
```

Comment: Message: Too few arguments to function Welcome::payment_page(), 0 passed

Comment: i think it is problem with URL i submited.

Comment: Check your URL. Should be: "<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('Welcome/payment');?>">"

Comment: no it is `Welcome/payment_page()`

Comment: My point of view is that "payment_page()" function has a parameter (in this case an array) therefore calling that URL without the expected parameter will give you an error.

Comment: so when form action what i pass array as variable.

Answer (score 0):

Kumar, you are getting a "Severity: Warning" message because you are using the [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function which accepts only an array. SO you should check if $data is an array before supplying it to the function. You can use [is_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) the function.

```
 public function payment_page($data){
   $other_data=array(
    'cardname' => $this->input->post('cardname'),
       'cardno'=> $this->input->post('cardno'),
      'cardcvv'=> $this->input->post('cardcvv'),
    'cardmonth'=>$this->input->post('cardmonth'),
    'cardyear' =>$this->input->post('cardyear')
    );
   if(is_array($data)) {
      return array_merge($data, $other_data);
   }
   
   return $other_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you submit your form on **payment_page** function without parameters
I think  you meant to submit it to the payment function  because you call and pass the array to **payment_page** from the payment function

if that is the case
you should consider submitting your form like this

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= site_url('Welcome/payment_page');?>">
```

you need to change nothing on the payment function so it's still like this

```
public function payment(){
    
     $data['userid']  = $this->input->post('userid');
     $data['payment']  = $this->input->post('payment');
        if(!empty($data)){
            $this->payment_page($data); //passing data into another function
         }
         $this->load->view('frontend/include/header');
         $this->load->view('frontend/payment');
    }
```

on payment_page  function try to handle the array like this

```
public function payment_page($data = null){
   $other_data=array(
       'cardname' => $this->input->post('cardname'),
       'cardno'=> $this->input->post('cardno'),
       'cardcvv'=> $this->input->post('cardcvv'),
       'cardmonth'=>$this->input->post('cardmonth'),
       'cardyear' =>$this->input->post('cardyear')
    );
   $main_data = array_merge($data, $other_data);
    
    
}
```

I hope it solve your problem